# Agree followed by the subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctives

Is it possible to use subjunctive with AGREE like this?

Everybody **agreed** that the appointment **take** place the next day.

I hear that it's not something usual. But is it really wrong?

I hanker to know the grammatical aspect of the issue.

Comment: Why are you asking? Do you want to know if this sentence you found is correct because you're interested in learning from the grammar, or would you like a natural way to express this idea? Please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: It is wrong. You need a “would” in there - “that the appointment would take place…”.